# How to pass to when array of deferred with their own callbacks

Tags: jquery, promise, deferred

Is it possible to pass to `$.when` array of deferred with their own callbacks? So I want each callback to be called after all deferred are resolved in order they are passed to `$.when`.

For instance in example below callback is called immediately after appropriate deferred is resolved and only general callback in `$.when` is called after all deferred is done

```
var d1 = $.Deferred();
var d2 = $.Deferred();

d1.done(function(result){alert('d1 is done');});
d2.done(function(result){alert('d2 is done');});

$.when(d1, d2).done(function(result){
alert('here only general callback is called');
});

d1.resolve();

setTimeout(function(){d2.resolve();}, 3000);
```

**EDIT:**
 Where I need to use it. Let's say I have several functions:

```
function SomeFunction1(){
var d = $.Deferred();

//if I define callback here it will call immediately after resolve
//d.done(function(result){
//// do something with result
//});

//$.ajax() or $.get() or $('#someID').load() or whatever else or just d.resolve
d.resolve('someData1');

return d.promise();
}

function SomeFunction2(){
var d = $.Deferred();

//if I define callback here it will call immediately after resolve
//d.done(function(result){
//// do something with result
//});

//$.ajax() or $.get() or $('#someID').load() or whatever else or just d.resolve
d.resolve('someData2');

return d.promise();
}

...

function SomeFunctionN(){
var d = $.Deferred();

//if I define callback here it will call immediately after resolve
//d.done(function(result){
//// do something with result
//});

//$.ajax() or $.get() or $('#someID').load() or whatever else or just d.resolve
d.resolve('someDataN');

return d.promise();
}
```

Then in some case I need to call only one of these functions, in some other case two of them, in third situation all of them:

```
1: $.when(SomeFunction1()).done(function(result){
//callback defined inside SomeFunction1
});

2: $.when(SomeFunction1(), SomeFunction2()).done(function(result){
//callbacks defined inside SomeFunction1 and SomeFunction2
});

3: $.when(SomeFunction1(), SomeFunction2(), ... , SomeFunctionN()).done(function(result){
//callbacks defined inside SomeFunction1, ... , SomeFunctionN
});
```

And callbacks on success and on error should be defined inside these functions but execute only AFTER all of called functions return result.

Is it possible?

Comment: I'm confused what your goal is, as your code already does what you require: https://jsfiddle.net/rq3r398q/. Note that it's always best to test code with `console.log` as `alert()` can cause erratic behaviour with timers and async operations.

Comment: You seem to want to change the behaviour of when the `done` callback of `d1` is called. Why would you do that? If possible, it would make your code quite unreadable: people expect the `done` callback to get executed as soon as the promise, on which it is defined, gets resolved. Yet, you want it to get called later.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I want all callbacks will be called only after all of deferred are resolved. In example I showed that each callback calls immediately after appropriate deferred are resolved

Comment: You mean the `d1 is done` and `d2 is done` callbacks? If so, put them in the call to `$.when` - that's what it's for.

Comment: @trincot Does it mean that its impossible to do this?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What if I don't know how many deferreds will be passed to `$.when` and want to get an array of deferreds with callbacks, defined in the thirty part function?

Comment: @ivanblin, if you don't want the `done` callback on d1 to be called when it gets resolved, then you shouldn't define that callback on `done`, because that is what it is for. It is not a matter of impossible or possible. Just don't define them. It is really bad design to want to tamper with the meaning of `done`. Don't go that way. Like others have said: if you only want something to happen when d1 and d2 are both resolved, then put your code in `$.when(d1, d2).done`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is not any type of behavior that is built into promises, you could implement your own.  jQuery will call `.done()` when that particular promise is done (not when the group promise is done) so you will have to specifiy the callback a different way.

One scheme would be for you to add a `.cb` property to each promise and when the whole group is done that callback will get called.  You can then make a superset of `$.when` that will look for that callback and call it if it exists when the whole group is done:

```
$.whenAfter = function(promiseArray){
    return $.when.apply($, promiseArray).then(function() {
        var results = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        promiseArray.forEach(function(p, index) {
            if (p.cb) {
                p.cb(results[index]);
            }
        });
        return results;
    });
}
```

Or, if you don't want to add the property to the promise, you could pass a separate callback array that corresponds to the promiseArray:

```
$.whenAfter = function(promiseArray, callbackArray){
    return $.when.apply($, promiseArray).then(function() {
        var results = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        promiseArray.forEach(function(p, index) {
            var cb = callbackArray[index];
            if (cb) {
                cb(results[index]);
            }
        });
        return results;
    });
}
```

---

If you have callbacks that must remain internal to your functions that you don't want to execute until some other set of operations are done, then I'd suggest you pass in a promise and you execute those callbacks when that promise is resolved.

```
function SomeFunction1(p1){
     var p2 = $.ajax(...);
     // now wait for both our async operation and some other async operation
     // to be done before carrying out the rest of our business
     $.when(p1, p2).then(function(a1, a2) {
         // now everything else is done too so we can carry out the rest of our business
     });

     // return p2 so other things can know when this ajax operation is done
     return p2;
}
```

And, you could combine multiple of these like this:

```
var def = $.Deferred();
var p = def.promise();

$.when(SomeFunction1(p), SomeFunction2(p), SomeFunction3(p)).then(def.resolve, ref.reject);
```

My experience with promises, tells me this is ugly code, but I'm not sure at the moment how to make this particular type of solution work cleaner.

---

Personally, I think I'd just make SomeFunctionX return both a promise and a callback so the callback can be called from the outside where we actually know things are done:

```
function SomeFunction1(){
     var p = $.ajax(...);
     function callback() {
         // do something here after we're done and others are done too
     } 
     return {promise: p, callback: callback}
}
```

Then, at the point you want to call several functions, you put them in an array and iterate over that array, collecting results and calling callbacks when appropriate:

```
  var funcs = [SomeFunction1, SomeFunction2, SomeFunction3];

  var callbacks = [];
  var promises = funcs.map(function(fn) {
      var retVal = fn();
      callbacks.push(retVal.callback);
      return retVal.promise;
  });
  $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
      callbacks.forEach(function(cb, index) {
          cb(args[index]);
      })
  });
```

And, you could make this into a reusable function that you would just pass an array of functions that returned the right data structure (promise and callback):

```
function runAll(funcs) {
    var callbacks = [];
    var promises = funcs.map(function (fn) {
        var retVal = fn();
        // if it only returns only a thenable (not our data structure), then just return the promise
        // this allows you to mix in functions that just return a promise
        if (typeof retVal.then === "function") {
            // assume no callback
            callbacks.push(null);
            return retVal;
        }
        callbacks.push(retVal.callback);
        return retVal.promise;
    });
    return $.when.apply($, promises).done(function () {
        try {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            callbacks.forEach(function (cb, index) {
                if (cb) {
                    cb(args[index]);
                }
            });
        } catch(e) {
            // if any callback throws an exception, then reject
            return $.Deferred().reject(e);
        }
    });
});

var funcs = [SomeFunction1, SomeFunction2, SomeFunction3];

runAll(funcs).done(function(results) {
    // all done here
}).fail(function(err) {
    // some sort of error here
});
```

---

P.S. If you're using async operations that already create and return a promise such as `$.get()`, then you should not be creating your own deferred.  That is a [promise anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns).  You should just be returning the promise that has already been created.

Comment: have that old problem where `results` of `$.when` isn't array, have to loop arguments. Although I think in jQ 3 they changed all that

Comment: @charlietfl - Oh yeah, I hate jQuery promises in that way.  I will fix.

Comment: each argument is array  too...I forget index that response data is in

Comment: @charlietfl - I'm just passing the argument through as it comes.  Sometimes it's an array, sometimes it's a value (thanks to the stupidity of jQuery).  The callback can adapt to whatever the result is as it should be known to that specific callback.  I'm not spreading it into separate arguments auto-magically like jQuery does.  That's a terrible practice and I won't perpetuate it.  Notice, I also made `$.whenAfter()` accept an array of promises too - refusing to perpetuate that mess that `$.when()` does.

Comment: oh yeah..i'm thinking of ajax promises where results in when is array

Comment: @charlietfl - This will work fine with `$.ajax()` promises too.  The callback will get a single argument that will be an array of three values.

Comment: @jfriend00 So you propose me pass two different arrays with promises and callbacks and just loop through second one on `$.when` is done. I hoped that there is another way, but ok

Comment: @ivanblin - That's my second option.  The first option adds a callback property to each promise (which is cleaner in my opinion).  Unless you're going to hack your promises and change the behavior of `.done()` to something non-standard, there is no other way.  You have to implement your own scheme to track a list of callbacks and to call them and I've provided two ways to do that.

Comment: @ivanblin - If you backed up a few steps and described your actual problem, we might be able to find a better way to solve that problem using standard promise behavior.  What you are asking for is unusual so if we understood the real problem being solved, we might be able to offer other (or even better) options.  FYI, this is always the case on stack overflow.  If you explain the actual problem you are trying to solve rather than issues with the solution you have chosen, you allow us to offer a wider range of good solutions.

Comment: @ivanblin - Your edit doesn't not explain that actual ***why*** you think you need this unusual behavior.  Again, you are just describing your proposed solution, not the actual problem.  If you have N async operations and you want to execute some function when those N async operations are done, you would typically just use `$.when()` or `Promise.all()` with those N async operations and have a single callback that executes when the N operations are done.  That is usually how it is done.  You haven't yet explained ***why*** you need something different than the usual case.

Comment: @ivanblin - It appears to me that your callbacks are just defined in the wrong place.  If they depend upon other operations, they need to be defined at a higher level or you can pass in a promise that when it's resolved, you can then execute those promises.  I'm quite sure we could come up with an elegant solution if we knew the real problem and saw and understood the real code.  We are 98% more effective with great answers when we see the real code and the real problem, not pseudo code.

Comment: @ivanblin - I added two more options.  I think I like the last one best.  Callbacks are actually called from the place that knows when everything is done.

Comment: @jfriend00 The last one is pretty good solution but it has little disadvantage: how to pass result of promise to callback.
**Why** do I need this is really hard to explain but, believe me, I do need it and I do need it to be done in the way I'm trying to describe

Comment: @ivanblin - I modified the last one to pass thru the result.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a callback array and loop through that in `$.when()`

```js
var funcs = {},
  promises = [],
  callbacks = [];
// create 5 functions and promises 
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

  (function(i) {
    funcs[i] = function() {
      console.log('Data in func #' + (i + 1) + ':', this.data)
    }
    promises[i] = $.Deferred();
    // push specific callback for each promise into array
    promises[i].then(function(result) {
      callbacks[i] = funcs[i].bind({
        data: result
      })
    });
    // random resolve times
    setTimeout(function() {
      promises[i].resolve('Promise #' + (i + 1))
    }, Math.random() * 1500);

  })(i)

}



$.when.apply(null, promises).done(function() {
  console.log('start callbacks loop');
  callbacks.forEach(function(fn) {
    fn();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Another implementation, but the main thought is the same as @jfriend00 suggested in the previous answer